# is it okay to call a private static method outside the class

Tags: python, oop

In python, is it okay to call a private static method outside the class? The class is from an external module, so I can't move it outside the class, but the method is useful for me.

```py
class Vector:
    @staticmethod
    def _add(a,b):
        return a + b

# is it okay to do:
Vector._add(1,2)
```

By "is it okay", I mean in terms of good practices/PEP guidelines.

Comment: @TimRoberts - Python does have [Private variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=private#private-variables), though not in the sense of, say, C++.

Comment: You have a couple of issues with private methods. If its done with `__` double underscores, its name mangled with the class name to make it hard to get via class inheritance - so you've reduced polymorphism. And generally, they are not part of the public API and implementers can change them at will without notice. if you don't mind the risk, then call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking in languages without proper method privacy, such as Python and Perl, an underscore prefix in a method name is an indication that the author of the class does *not* want you to call that method.

That goes for use outside the class, in subclasses, in related classes, etc.

The exception to that would be if the author has explicitly documented (either as part of the class's formal documentation or in code comments) that the method is part of the supported API. Reasons why an author may want to name supported methods with an underscore prefix might include:

- backwards compatibility with older versions where it was not supported; or
- the method is supported because it's useful for subclassing, but the author doesn't want it to be exposed to "normal users".